# What will a sphere look like if it's unwrapped?

Tags: geometry, 3d, spheres

I actually google alot, but all results are related to 3D design apps like blender bla bla bla, No direct answers or even something to help. I tried to imagine it like some triangles arranged and all their top vertices are coincident, Any illustrations for that? If you can't understand, I meant like if we unwrap a cone, it will be a circular sector, what about the sphere?

Comment: Google "map projections" (which is specifically about unwrapping the Earth, but applies equally well to any sphere). This problem has been thought about for centuries, and no one has found a canonical, "good" answer.

Comment: There is no way to unwrap a sphere perfectly. As stated in the comment above, if you’re familiar with projections, you’d know that ALL projections of the Earth involve some form of distortion, either in shape or size. The reason should be clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way by which a sphere can be "unwrapped" in the same sense as a cylinder or a cone can be unwrapped. The reason is that a sphere has [intrinsic curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature) - essentially, the [geometry on a sphere is too different from the geometry on a plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_geometry#/media/File:Triangles_(spherical_geometry).jpg). Angles of a triangle on a sphere do not add up to 180°, on a cone or a cylinder they do.